# Modern LaTeX template

Tags: templates

I have been looking for modern LaTeX templates, and have found several that I like but only from pdf-finished versions. All the LaTeX templates I could find from previous responses where still with the old LaTeX fonts.

More specifically, does someone knows where can I access the template for a similar kind of design: http://politicalscience.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/documents/KarlEoE.pdf or http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.27.4.3

If you look closely at these links, you willl notice that these more recent LaTeX publications have been using a more grayish font, does anyone know what font color should I be using to obtain that tone?

Thanks,

AG

Comment: These documents were not even produced with LaTeX. If you look at the meta data you will find for "Oil-Led Development", that it was made with "3B2 Total Publishing System 7.51c/W" and "A Century of US Central Banking" is created by "PDFplus".

Comment: You might still be interested in these "actual" LaTeX templates: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/articles

Comment: @percusse Want to make your comment into a short answer?

Comment: @HenriMenke: How is some randomly editable PDF metadata a proof for your claim *"These documents were not even produced with LaTeX"*  ?!?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle You need Occam's Razor.

Comment: @percusse: Oh, I have it. I just don't jump to the most easy conclusion unconditionally. Otherwise I'd still be convinced that the earth is a flat disk orbitted by the sun... Regarding said 'PDFplus': it is produced by a company named 'Atypon' which says on its website: *"Our standard input formats are PDF and NLM/JATS"* and: *"Add reference linking and citing articles to your PDFs with PDFplus."* -- Now you... (You need to develop some healthy scepticism against your Razor tool!)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Occam's Razor works on the possibilities that are not falsified **and** equally likely, **not** every possiblity.

Comment: @percusse: Agreed. Which means: it is not applicable here.

Comment: @percusse: Oh, and look at this -- http://imamci.oxfordjournals.org/content/9/4/local/back-matter.pdf

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I assume you know what PDFPlus is used for right? TeX engine and TeX typesetting is not the same thing. LaTeX is not the only system. For example, our Stephen Lehmke has another system called `docscape` which is definitely not LaTeX and uses TeX engine. Please check what you are talking about before you go berserk about a stupid detail. In your link it expicitly mentions *TeX Interpreter*.

Comment: @percusse: discussing this "detail" is finished here for me :-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I hope so.

Comment: @percusse: Especially since the *"stupid detail I went berserk about"* was aimed at statements about ***PDFs*** (about which I know lots), not statements about TeX/LaTeX/docscape/TeX-interpreters (which I know next to nothing about). And additionally since the OP's author is an 11-reput-newbie, whom you can't expect to know the fine details setting apart the things you mentioned, which many even seasoned LaTeX users would be unable to explain properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for keywords `journal of economic perspectives latex` a package called `vertex` is cited where you can introduce a style file for the link. And also some cite `sw55jep.sty`.

Comment: It's been a while, but wanted to say your suggestion was spot on. I have been using sw55jep.sty and it has worked great all these years. Thank you!